# How to add build configuration options for specific external http_archive dependencies in bazel?

Tags: bazel

I'm currently importing grpc as an external http_archive in a Bazel C++ project. I would like to build with the flag `--config=dbg`, as specified in the project's bazel.rc file, [here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/a5ce92d8cf33cd29d93e8700bc8891cadf60ba43/tools/bazel.rc), but just for this dependency. Is there any way for me to do this without downloading the repository and editing the internal bazel build files?

Answer (score 1):

Configurations in `bazel.rc` files in external dependencies are not automatically applied, see:

[How does tools/bazel.rc work with external Workspace dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47314657/how-does-tools-bazel-rc-work-with-external-workspace-dependencies?rq=1)

As mentioned there, you can copy those configurations to your project's `tools/bazel.rc` file